# How this line is executed in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to compare character to ascii values for that i am using the bellow code.It works fine but I have a doubt.how the bellow line was executed.
I didn't convert s.charAt(i) to int but how it was compared with ascii value.

**code 1:**

```
if(s.charAt(i)>='a' && s.charAt(i)<='z'){
}
```

**code 2:**

```
if((int)s.charAt(i)>='a' && (int)s.charAt(i)<='z'){
}
```

In above two codes are working same.I need to know the difference between code1 and code2. Can any one help me to know this?

Comment: Use `javap -v className.class` to see the actualy bytecode and what are the actual values being used.. It is always handy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison operators work on numerical operands -- or, more specifically, on operands that can be converted to numerical operands ([JLS 15.20.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1)). So even in your "code 1" example, the four chars (two from `s.charAt(i)`, and the two literals) are automatically promoted to int for purposes of the comparison.

The first step of the comparison is to use "binary numeric conversion" to get both operands to be of the same type ([JLS 5.6.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2)). Basically, they're widened to the narrowest type that can accommodate both types, which in the case of `char` is `int`. Once that's done, it's just a straightforward, signed comparison.